# Add multiple users to list and save the same list data in the database In REST API service

Tags: java, mysql, json, rest

I am trying to add list of users to the list and that list should add in the database. But in the database it is saving only last user data in the list(means one user only not multiple users). Below is my code,

**PersistenceServiceImpl.java**

```
public List<CtxtReceiverConfig> saveUser(List<CtxtReceiverConfig> users,CtxtUserMaster createdBy) {
    List<CtxtReceiverConfig> receiver = new ArrayList<>();
    CtxtReceiverConfig user = new CtxtReceiverConfig();
    try{
        Date currentDate = getCurrentDate();
        for(CtxtReceiverConfig receiverConfig : users){
            user.setReceiverFirstName(receiverConfig.getReceiverFirstName());
            user.setReceiverLastName(receiverConfig.getReceiverLastName());
            user.setReceiverEmail(receiverConfig.getReceiverEmail());
            user.setReceiverPhoneNo(receiverConfig.getReceiverPhoneNo());
            user.setCreatedBy(createdBy.getUserId());
            user.setCreatedDate(currentDate);
            user.setIsActive("Y");
            user.setReceiverStatus("Invite sent");

            user = receiverConfigDao.saveAndFlush(user);
            receiver.add(user);
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return receiver;
}
```

**MainController.java**

```
            @POST
            @Path("/group/setup")
            @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            @StatusCodes ({
            @ResponseCode ( code = 304, condition = "Not Modified"),
            @ResponseCode ( code = 200, condition = "Successfully Saved"),
            @ResponseCode ( code = 409, condition = "Duplicate Name"),
        })
        public Response saveGroupInitial(JSONObject json) {
            String result = null;
            String sessionUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
                try {
                    CtxtUserMaster currentUser = restService.findByEmailId(sessionUser);

                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mms");
                    Date date1 = new Date();
                    String dateString = dateFormat.format(date1);
                    Date createdAt = dateFormat.parse(dateString);

                    List<CtxtReceiverConfig> userList = new ArrayList<>();
                    CtxtReceiverConfig receiver = new CtxtReceiverConfig();

                    if(json.has("addedUsers")){
                    JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("addedUsers");
                    if (jsonArray.length()>0) { 
                        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) { 
                            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            receiver.setReceiverFirstName(jsonObj.getString("firstName"));
                            receiver.setReceiverLastName(jsonObj.getString("lastName"));
                            receiver.setReceiverEmail(jsonObj.getString("emailId"));
                            receiver.setReceiverPhoneNo(jsonObj.getString("phoneNo"));
                        } 
                        userList.add(receiver);
                    }
                    }

                    JSONObject jsonObject = restService.saveGroupInitial(currentUser, createdAt,userList);
                    result = jsonObject.getString("Status");

                } catch(Exception e) {
                    log.error("Error saving group..");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("Created")){
                    return Response.status(Status.OK).build();
                }
                else {
                    return Response.status(Status.CONFLICT).build();
                }
        }
```

**JSON Data** I am passing

```
{
    "addedUsers": [{
        "firstName": "tom",
        "lastName": "cn",
        "emailId": "tom@gmail.com",
        "phoneNo": "7854123698"
    }, {
        "firstName": "jerry",
        "lastName": "cn",
        "emailId": "jerry@yahoo.com",
        "phoneNo": "41569872368"
    }]
}
```

Please help me out what I am doing wrong in this.